# How to measure X labels and get the biggest value to a variable?

Tags: vb.net

Using `For Each` loop I measure the size of "X" labels from a `FlowLayoutPanel` control:

```
For Each _Label As Label In _FlowLayoutPanel.Controls
    Dim _TextSize As System.Drawing.Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(_Label.Text, _Label.Font)
    _Label.Size = New Size(_TextSize.Width, _TextSize.Height)                
Next
```

How can I get to a variable the biggest `Width` value of all those `Label`s widths?

Comment: The below two comments answer you question correctly. After reading your comments a few times, is there something we are missing? Do you have numerous 'Texts' you need to itterate through as well as labels?

Comment: Yes both answers are 100% correct, it was my fault, I was "calling" the `Private Sub` which contains this part of code in wrong way... Sorry!!!

Comment: No worries glad you've got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use a variable and only change the value of that variable when the size of the current label is bigger than the variable's value?

Something like that:

```
Dim maxWidth as Integer = -1

For Each ...
    currentWidth = ...
    If currentWidth > maxWidth Then
        maxWidth = currentWidth
    End If
Next

MsgBox(maxWidth)
```

---

Edit:

If you are familiar with LINQ or if you like to get to know LINQ you could even get your wanted information in one line

```
Dim maxWidth As Integer = _FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label) _
                                                   .Select(Of Integer)(Function(x As Label) TextRenderer.MeasureText(x.Text, x.Font).Width) _
                                                   .Max
```

Although the possible functions might vary depending on the data type of the `Controls` collection.

Comment: As I said to "Video baba" below, how can I get **only** the biggest `Width` value at the end? Because If I add for example `MsgBox(LabelMaxWidth)` out of the `For Each` loop to get the biggest `Width` value, it gives me the `Width` values of all `Label`s one by one!!!

Comment: If you get all widths, then you are not outside of the For..Next loop, try my edit (`MsgBox` in code part)

Comment: Your answer is 100% correct, it was my fault, I was "calling" the Private Sub which contains this part of code in wrong way... Sorry!!! Thank you very much for your additional valuable informations about LINQ!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim LabelMaxWidth As Integer = 0
For Each _Label As Label In _FlowLayoutPanel.Controls
    Dim _TextSize As System.Drawing.Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(_Label.Text, _Label.Font)
    _Label.Size = New Size(_TextSize.Width, _TextSize.Height)
    If _Label.Width > LabelMaxWidth Then LabelMaxWidth = _Label.Width
Next
```

Comment: Yes but how can I get **only** the biggest `Width` value at the end? Because If I add for example `MsgBox(LabelMaxWidth)` out of the `For Each` loop to get the biggest `Width` value, it gives me the `Width` values of all `Label`s one by one!!!

Comment: I accepted Nostromo's answer as the correct answer just because he answered first. Both answers are the same and correct of course!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum `Width` also by using some [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq):

```
MsgBox(FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.
                       OfType(Of Label).
                       Max(Function(l) TextRenderer.MeasureText(l.Text, l.Font).Width))
```